# How to extract time from Datetime

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, datetime

Im trying to extract time from Datetime and then converting it into int to add 10 to it and then convert it into Datetime and store in the database. But I keep getting following error:

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Following is the code:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection);
            String query = "Select timings from topogen.token_gen order by timings desc limit 0,1;";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);

            String location = "";
            conn.Open();
            MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            string timings="";

           while( r.Read()){
            timings = r["timings"].ToString();}

           DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(timings); //error appears here
           timings = time.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
           time = DateTime.Parse(timings);



           long  t = time.Ticks;
           t += 10;
           timings = t.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
           TextBox1.Text = timings;
           time = DateTime.ParseExact(timings, "HH:mm:ss", null);
            this.Location = location;
            conn.Close();
```

Comment: can you please add, what `timings` is (when the error occurs)?

Comment: @cramopy its values is taken from the database (from the last row in table)

Comment: @puffles yes, but *what is it*?.  The error you've got is a parsing error, and this is because the value of `timings` can't be parsed to a `DateTime`..

Comment: your `timings` does not recognize as a `DateTime`

Comment: Making the code work still won't make it do anything. Adding ten ticks will not make a difference in the number of seconds. You would need to add at least 10000000 ticks for the value to change.

Comment: As an aside, it's not clear why you're parsing to `DateTime`, converting to `string`, parsing to `DateTime` again, getting the `Ticks` adding 10 (1,000 *nanoseconds*), converting to `string` again, then parsing to `DateTime` again.  Assuming you really want to add 10 ticks: `time = DateTime.Parse(timings).AddTicks(10)` is all you need.  Other `AddX` methods available if you really wanted to add seconds, minutes etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `r["timings"].ToString()` generates a string representation that your `CurrentCulture` does not have a [standard date and time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx). That's why your `DateTime.Parse` throws `FormatException`.

1. Change your `timings` column type to [`datetime`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) type *even* it doesn't.
2. Use [`GetDateTime()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getdatetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of `MySqlDataReader` to get it's value as `DateTime`

---

```
MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if(r.Read())
{
   DateTime timings = r.GetDateTime(0);
}
```

Let's look the rest of your code. They have also some mistakes.

```
long  t = time.Ticks;
```

With this, you will get Ticks of your `DateTime` which looks like for example; `2,193,385,800,000,000`.

```
t += 10;
```

With this, you will get `2,193,385,800,000,010` which is okey for now because it is a `long` and this is just an addition.

```
timings = t.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Here a mistake. You try to get string representation of your `long` which uses [`NumberFormatInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) of your `CurrentCulture`. It doesn't even use [`DateTimeFormatInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx). That's your your `timings` will be `HH:mm:ss` as a string. And you will try to parse it as `DateTime.ParseExact(timings, "HH:mm:ss", null)` which is equal to `DateTime.ParseExact("HH:mm:ss", "HH:mm:ss", null)`. As you can see, this parsing operation will fail.

Consider to changing your logic.

Comment: thanks , it worked but also I realized that the table was empty and it was passing a null value. So, changed that as well

Comment: @puffles Good to hear it